# Getting error while setting the argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm getting an error while setting the variable in argument.

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    case $1 in
       '--pub') fun2exec="loadpubserveripip" ;;
       '--tourney') fun2exec="loadtourneyserver" ;;
       '--standby') fun2exec="loadpubserverwg" ;;
       '--help') fun2exec="help" ;;
       '--port') port="$2" ; shift ;;
       '--matchid') matchid="$3" ; shift ;;
       *) echo "Argument Error, Please type bash script.sh --help for All Available Arguments"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    shift done

if [ -z "$fun2exec" ] ; then
    help
    exit 2 fi

if [ -z "$port" ] ; then
    echo "Please Provide Server Port 11011/22022/33033/44044/55055"
    exit 3 fi

$fun2exec

exit 0
```

This is the part of code.
Whenever I execute, I get the output as below

```
+ '[' 5 -gt 0 ']'
+ case $1 in
+ fun2exec=loadtourneyserver
+ shift
+ '[' 4 -gt 0 ']'
+ case $1 in
+ port=11011
+ shift
+ shift
+ '[' 2 -gt 0 ']'
+ case $1 in
+ matchid=
+ shift
+ shift
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ '[' -z loadtourneyserver ']'
+ '[' -z 11011 ']'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ echo 'Please Provide MatchID'
Please Provide MatchID
+ exit 3
```

I execute script with below command

```
bash -x test.sh --tourney --port 11011 --matchid 1
```

Can someone help me to fix this, I am very new to scripting

Comment: Why are you setting `matchid` to `$3` instead of `$2`? Also, your script seems to be missing some required line breaks (before the `done` and `fi` keywords).

Comment: port is at $2..

Comment: No, the port number has been shifted out of the argument list at that point. The only things left are "--matchid" in `$1` and "1" in `$2`.

Comment: So I should use $2 for both port and matchid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: use `matchid="$2"` instead of `matchid="$3"`.

Long answer: I think you're misunderstanding how `shift` and `$1`, `$2`, etc work. `$1`, `$2`, etc contain *all* of the arguments passed to the script, including flag arguments like "--tourney" and "--port". `shift` removes the first argument from the list, and the remaining arguments "shift" down the list, so what was `$2` becomes `$1`, what was `$3` becomes `$2`, etc.

So at the beginning of the script, `$1` is "--tourney", `$2` is "--port", `$3` is "11011", `$4` is "--matchid", and `$5` is "1".

The first time through the `while` loop, `case $1` matches "--tourney", so it sets `fun2exec="loadtourneyserver"` and then runs `shift`. So now `$1` is "--port", `$2` is "11011", `$3` is "--matchid", and `$4` is "1".

The second time through the `while` loop, `case $1` matches "--port", so it sets `port="$2"` (which is "11011" *because that argument got shifted from `$3` to `$2`). It then runs `shift` *twice*, removing the first two arguments. So now `$1` is "--matchid", and `$2` is "1".

The third time through the `while` loop, `case $1` finally matches "--matchid". At this point the "1" that's supposed to be the `matchid` value has been shifted all the way down to `$2`, so that's what you need to assign to the `matchid` variable.

It'll then `shift` twice more, removing the last arguments from the list. At this point, `$1`, `$2`, etc are all unassigned, so `[ $# -gt 0 ]` is false and the loop exits.